# Find the outer measure $\mu^*$ induced by $\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $X$ be a set, $S=\{\emptyset,X\}$, and define $\mu:S\to[0,\infty)$ by $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu(X)=1$. Determine the outer measure $\mu^*$ induced by $\mu$, and find the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets.

I know that outer measure $\mu^*$ must satisfy the properties that (1) $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$, and (2) that $\mu^*$ is countably monotone, but I am unsure of how to construct $\mu^*$ from $\mu$.

Comment: State the definition of outer measure induced by $\mu$, and explain where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I have already provided the definition of outer measure (satisfying the two above properties). It seems to me that $\mu$ already satisfies these properties, so $\mu^*=\mu$, so I am unsure of whether I need to confirm this, or if this is not in fact true, how to construct $\mu^*$.

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to compute $\mu^* A$ for an arbitrary $A \subset X$. Then you need to figure out what sets are measurable from the definition.

Comment: No, you haven't provided the definition, it should be something like $$\mu^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k) : E \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k,\,\, E_k \in S\right\}$$ And $\mu^*$ should be defined on every subset of $X$, not just on $S$, so in general you won't have $\mu^* = \mu$ since $\mu^*$ has a larger domain.

Comment: @Bungo what I have typed is how my textbook (Royden 4th ed.) has defined outer measure.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think it is particularly helpful to answer a question simply by telling me that it is straightforward.

Comment: @Bungo In my textbook: A set function $\mu^*:2^X\to [0,\infty]$ is called an outer measure provided $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu^*$ is countably monotone.

Comment: Well, you need to do a little work. Given an arbitrary set $A$, how many $\mu$-measurable sets are there whose union contains $A$?

Comment: @MathStudent1324 Yes, those are the axioms of an outer measure. But what I wrote in my comment above is the definition of the **specific** outer measure **induced by** (i.e. extended from) a premeasure $\mu$, which is what you need to use here.

Comment: How does your textbook create an induced outer measure, or how are they related? I am only aware of one definition which the the one that @Bungo gave above. (I don't have my Royden at hand.)

Comment: My earlier comment regarding straightforward assumed the above definition of induced outer measure. Without a definition of induced outer measure it is impossible :-).

Comment: I just got a chance to look at Royden 4th edition. See page 350, Theorem 9 (section 17.4, "Construction of Outer Measures", in case your page numbering is different), which defines the outer measure induced by $\mu$ and proves that is indeed an outer measure (satisfies the axioms given in the OP). Note also that your question is problem 21 at the end of the same section.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you, this is helpful! Must have missed this page in my book.

Comment: @Bungo Okay, so by Theorem 9, let $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$. Then for a set $E\in X$ where $E\neq\emptyset$, define $\mu^*(E)=\inf\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(E_k)$, where $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of sets in $S$ that cover $E$. Then the set function $\mu^*:2^X\to[0,\infty]$ is the outer measure $\mu^*$ induced by $\mu$. So, it is already true that the measure of the empty set is 0. I am confused about the rest though. $\mu^*(X)$ should still be one, but do I also have to consider all subsets of $X$? How do I do this?

Comment: @MathStudent1324 I'll go ahead and post an answer since this comment section is becoming a bit cluttered.

Answer (score 3):

Royden defines the outer measure induced by a set function $\mu : S \to [0,\infty]$ (where $S$ is an arbitrary collection of subsets of $X$) as follows: set $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$, and for any nonempty subset $E \subseteq X$, put
$$\mu^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k) : E \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k,\ \ E_k \in S\right\}$$

Let's give a name to the set in braces; I'll call it $A$. Note that $A$ is a subset of $[0, \infty]$.

In this problem, we have $S = \{\emptyset, X\}$, so in the union $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$, each $E_k$ is either $\emptyset$ or $X$.

Let $E$ be any nonempty subset of $X$. (I'm assuming that $X$ itself is nonempty.)

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)$ is either an integer or $\infty$, since the summands are all either $0$ or $1$. The only way the sum can be zero is if $E_k = \emptyset$ for all $k$, in which case $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k = \emptyset$, which does not contain $E$ as a subset.

So, $A$ doesn't contain $0$, hence its infimum must be at least $1$.

In fact, $A$ contains $1$, so its infimum is exactly $1$. To see this, let $E_1 = X$ and $E_k = \emptyset$ for all $k > 1$. Then $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k = X \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \cdots = X$, which certainly contains $E$ as a subset. Therefore $A$ contains $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k) = \mu(X) + \mu(\emptyset) + \mu(\emptyset) + \cdots = 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 1$.

We conclude that $\mu^*(E) = 1$ for any nonempty subset $E \subseteq X$, and of course $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$.

For the next step we want to know which $E \subseteq X$ satisfy the Caratheodory criterion
$$\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap E) + \mu^*(B \cap E^c)$$
for all $B \subseteq X$.

In particular, setting $B = X$, we see that such a set $E$ must satisfy
$$1 = \mu^*(X) = \mu^*(E) + \mu^*(E^c)$$
The terms on the RHS are either $0$ or $1$, so exactly one of them must be $0$ and the other must be $1$. In particular, since one of the terms must be zero, this means that either $E$ or $E^c$ must be $\emptyset$, and consequently either $E^c$ or $E$ must be $X$.

The above reasoning shows that the only subsets of $X$ which satisfy the Caratheodory criterion with respect to $\mu^*$ are $\emptyset$ and $X$, i.e. $S = \{\emptyset, X\}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets with respect to the measure induced by $\mu^*$.